# Найти для каждого ученика предмет с лучшим средним баллом за задания

Tags: sql, sqldeveloper

Есть таблица TASKS.

```
STUDENT_ID COURSE_ID DATE        TASK_NR FILE_NAME                POINTS    TASK_ID
---------- --------- -------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- ----------
10020011   I319      17.06.03          1 t3.txt                        8          3
10020014   I319      01.06.03          1 t7.txt                       10          4
10020015   I319      11.07.03          1 t8.txt                       10          5
10020011   I319      11.06.04          2 t2.txt                        7          6
10020015   I319      11.06.04          3 t2.txt                        6          7
10020013   I319      11.06.04          3 t3.txt                        8          8
10020011   Iad307    11.06.03          1 t1.txt                        5          9
10020011   Id310     12.06.03          1 t2.txt                       7         10
10020011   ID218     17.06.03          1 t3.txt                        8         11
10020014   Iad307    01.06.03          1 t7.txt                       10         12
10020015   Iad307    11.07.03          1 t8.txt                       10         13
```

Суть задачи - из таблицы TASKS получить для каждого ученика, к какому предмету его среднее количество баллов за задания лучшее.

Выглядеть должно так

```
STUDENT_ID COURSE_ID        AVG
---------- --------- ----------
10020011   ID218              8
10020013   ID218            9,5
10020014   I319              10
10020015   Iad307            10
```

Для начала я нахожу средний результат по баллам каждого предмета для каждого ученика

```
SELECT student_id, course_id, AVG(points) AS avg FROM tasks GROUP BY student_id, course_id 
ORDER BY student_id;

STUDENT_ID COURSE_ID        AVG
---------- --------- ----------
10020011   Id310              7
10020011   Iad307          5,75
10020011   I319               5
10020011   ID218              8
10020013   ID218            9,5
10020013   I319               8
10020014   I319              10
10020014   Iad307          6,25
10020014   ID218              6
10020015   Id309            5,5
10020015   I319               8
```

Далее я хочу получить ид ученика, ид курса и максимальное значение баллов по этому курсу для каждого ученика

```
SELECT student_id, course_id, MAX(avg) AS max FROM (
SELECT student_id, course_id, AVG(points) AS avg FROM tasks GROUP BY student_id, course_id
) GROUP BY student_id ORDER BY student_id;
```

Получаю ошибку

*ORA-00979: выражение не является выражением GROUP BY
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"*

Пробовал вариант

```
SELECT student_id, ANY_VALUE(course_id), MAX(avg) AS max FROM (
SELECT student_id, course_id, AVG(points) AS avg FROM tasks GROUP BY student_id, course_id
) GROUP BY student_id ORDER BY student_id;
```

Получаю ошибку

*ORA-00904: "ANU_VALUE": недопустимый идентификатор
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"*

Есть ли альтернатива ANY_VALUE или возможно другой способ решения задачи?

Comment: Задача не очень простая. Если есть возможность, введите данные в какой-нибудь online sandbox для sql - и укажите ссылку в задаче. Так будет больше шансов что вам помогут. Так как одно дело просто "поиграть" с запросами, а другое дело сначала создать тестовый полигон .

Comment: 1. Почему в ожидаемом результате "ID218    9,5" для студента 10020013, если у него в данных нет вообще такого курса?

Comment: 2. Исходя из ошибки "AN**U**_VALUE": недопустимый идентификатор", вы просто опечатались с AN**Y**_VALUE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробовал воспроизвести на `http://sqlfiddle.com/`.
Суть проблемы - в выборе значения из поля `course_id`, которое соответствует максимальному баллу из средних. Решить удалось двумя способами трехэтажными SELECT с помощью  1) `RANK()` и 2) `row_number()`. На мой взгляд, вариант № 1 более правильный, чем № 2, поскольку выводит все результаты для одного и того же студента, если максимальные баллы равны.
Исходные данные (Build Schema):

```
CREATE TABLE tasks
    ("STUDENT_ID" int, "COURSE_ID" varchar2(6), "DATE" varchar2(8), "TASK_NR" int, "FILE_NAME" varchar2(6), "POINTS" int, "TASK_ID" int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO tasks ("STUDENT_ID", "COURSE_ID", "DATE", "TASK_NR", "FILE_NAME", "POINTS", "TASK_ID")
         VALUES (10020011, 'I319', '17.06.03', 1, 't3.txt', 8, 3)
    INTO tasks ("STUDENT_ID", "COURSE_ID", "DATE", "TASK_NR", "FILE_NAME", "POINTS", "TASK_ID")
         VALUES (10020014, 'I319', '01.06.03', 1, 't7.txt', 10, 4)
    INTO tasks ("STUDENT_ID", "COURSE_ID", "DATE", "TASK_NR", "FILE_NAME", "POINTS", "TASK_ID")
         VALUES (10020015, 'I319', '11.07.03', 1, 't8.txt', 10, 5)
    INTO tasks ("STUDENT_ID", "COURSE_ID", "DATE", "TASK_NR", "FILE_NAME", "POINTS", "TASK_ID")
         VALUES (10020011, 'I319', '11.06.04', 2, 't2.txt', 7, 6)
    INTO tasks ("STUDENT_ID", "COURSE_ID", "DATE", "TASK_NR", "FILE_NAME", "POINTS", "TASK_ID")
         VALUES (10020015, 'I319', '11.06.04', 3, 't2.txt', 6, 7)
    INTO tasks ("STUDENT_ID", "COURSE_ID", "DATE", "TASK_NR", "FILE_NAME", "POINTS", "TASK_ID")
         VALUES (10020013, 'I319', '11.06.04', 3, 't3.txt', 8, 8)
    INTO tasks ("STUDENT_ID", "COURSE_ID", "DATE", "TASK_NR", "FILE_NAME", "POINTS", "TASK_ID")
         VALUES (10020011, 'Iad307', '11.06.03', 1, 't1.txt', 5, 9)
    INTO tasks ("STUDENT_ID", "COURSE_ID", "DATE", "TASK_NR", "FILE_NAME", "POINTS", "TASK_ID")
         VALUES (10020011, 'Id310', '12.06.03', 1, 't2.txt', 7, 10)
    INTO tasks ("STUDENT_ID", "COURSE_ID", "DATE", "TASK_NR", "FILE_NAME", "POINTS", "TASK_ID")
         VALUES (10020011, 'ID218', '17.06.03', 1, 't3.txt', 8, 11)
    INTO tasks ("STUDENT_ID", "COURSE_ID", "DATE", "TASK_NR", "FILE_NAME", "POINTS", "TASK_ID")
         VALUES (10020014, 'Iad307', '01.06.03', 1, 't7.txt', 10, 12)
    INTO tasks ("STUDENT_ID", "COURSE_ID", "DATE", "TASK_NR", "FILE_NAME", "POINTS", "TASK_ID")
         VALUES (10020015, 'Iad307', '11.07.03', 1, 't8.txt', 10, 13)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

SQL-запрос №1 - сначала усредняем баллы как в оригинальном коде, потом их ранжируем в обратном порядке с помощью `RANK()` (с рангом 1 самые большие значения), затем отбираем записи со значением ранга = 1. При этом могут появиться множественные значения для одного и того же `student_id`, если максимальные средние баллы по разным курсам равны:

```
SELECT student_id, course_id,  sred FROM (
SELECT student_id, course_id,  sred, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY sred DESC) as rank_sred FROM (
SELECT student_id, course_id, AVG(points) AS sred FROM tasks GROUP BY student_id, course_id
) GROUP BY student_id,course_id, sred ORDER BY student_id) WHERE RANK_SRED=1;
```

Результат 1 (студент № 14 в двух экземплярах с баллами 10 по двум курсам):

```
STUDENT_ID  COURSE_ID  SRED
10020011    ID218       8
10020013    I319        8
10020014    I319       10
10020014    Iad307     10
10020015    Iad307     10
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй способ - через `row_number()` - выбирает только первый результат из группы:

```
SELECT student_id, course_id,  sred FROM (
SELECT student_id, course_id,  sred, row_number() over (partition by student_id order by sred DESC) as row_n FROM (
SELECT student_id, course_id, AVG(points) AS sred FROM tasks GROUP BY student_id, course_id
) GROUP BY student_id,course_id, sred ORDER BY student_id) WHERE row_n=1;
```

Результат № 2 (студент № 14 в одном экземпляре)

```
STUDENT_ID  COURSE_ID   SRED
10020011    ID218        8
10020013    I319         8
10020014    I319        10
10020015    Iad307      10
```

Для понимания правильного результата - разобранные данные в Excel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]